# UITableViewCell action badge

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know how to implement an action badge, like the ones seen below with the price tags in them. The App Store has those too.

[alt text http://m.macupdate.com/images/screens/uploaded/30815_scr.png](http://m.macupdate.com/images/screens/uploaded/30815_scr.png)

Comment: please update screenshot or edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to set the `accessoryView` of a standard `UITableViewCell` to a `UIView`. You can just make them be standard `UIButtons`, set their background color and the label color and font.

If they're not meant to be interactive, then you can use a container `UIView` with a `UIImageView` in the background and a `UILabel` in the front added as subviews.

If you want to get fancy with it you'll have to subclass `UITableViewCell` and lay out the various bits yourself. It's not that difficult. The `TableViewSuite` sample code shows you how.

Comment: UIButtons sound like the way to go. However in the screenshot above, there is some kind of inner shadow and the bgcolor is more like a gradient. Is it an image or is it a UIButton property I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably a button with an image background. One clue is if the app does something different if you tap on the button part vs. the cell itself. If they both do the same thing then the accessoryView is probably a UIImageView. If it does something different then it's probably a UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is anyway within the framework to create this type of button.  You could fairly easily simulate it using your own custom images. What you want in this case is a stretchable image that does not distort as you resize the buttons.

Take a look at the following method on the UIImage class:

`- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight`